# the verb "linger" used with a gerund: is it possible?

Tags: verbs

Can the verb LINGER be used with a gerund?

He is lingering calling her.

I always linger doing my homework.

Comment: It is understandable, but I don't think I would use it. I might do so with a comma to make the _-ing_ phrase an afterthought: _He is lingering, calling for her_.

Comment: No: "linger" does not license gerund-participial complements.

Comment: Why did you have to let it linger?

Answer (score 1):

No, you wouldn’t hear it used like that.

Something more idiomatic would be saying that you “linger around/over” something, i.e. the idea of doing something, or the obligation/necessity to do it.

> I always linger around/over doing my homework.

> He is lingering around/over calling her.

Comment: "around" sounds wrong to me. Can't put into words exactly why, but it just does not seem altogether correct.